# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser

Tags: image, camera, picker

I'm using [This image picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6728) for selecting image from gallery / camera, you can see my manifest below

> My package name is: com.vowpay.vowpay

```
      <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.vowpay.vowpay"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

GETTING ERROR:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

AT LINE

```
       lifeCycleCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change you provider from

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.vowpay.vowpay"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

to

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.vowpay.vowpay.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and provider_path.xml should like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
<root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
    </paths>
```

Comment: Great. It works. But I don't think you need root-path.

Comment: may be.. but its totally works fine for every situation.